# Spring MVC using different part of hibernate validator in Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

My problem is that I wanna use just username and userpassword  hibernate validation for login page. Not  for also useremail.I kept useremail hibernate validation annotation for registration  page or something.So when I try at login page to login errors occured.(Please enter your email) But I dont want to include that.Just check for username and userpassword.How can I handle that?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String displayUserForm(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request){
            model.addAttribute("usertable",new usertable());
            return "login";
        }
```

Above is for going to login.jsp

```
private Integer userid;
     @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your username.")
     private String username;
     @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your password.")
     private String userpw;
      @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your email.")
      private String useremail;
```

Above is  part of pojo class

```
<div style="color:red">${errorMessage}</div>
    <form:form method="POST" commandName="usertable" action="/Proje/loginiscorrect">
        <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name :</td>
                <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="username" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User Password  :</td>
                <td><form:input path="userpw" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="userpw" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>                      
            <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="LOGIN"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

Above is login jsp page for checking errors if any errors coming up display message at same page

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loginiscorrect",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String LoginUser(@Valid kisitablo kisitablo, BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
bla bla}
```

Above is for check via hibernate validator from pojo class annotations .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done this way using `Hibernate Group`.

Create a marker interface for the group name

```
public interface LoginGroup {}
```

In you Domain object

```
private Integer userid;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your username.", groups={LoginGroup.class})
private String username;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your password.", groups={LoginGroup.class})
private String userpw;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your email.")
private String useremail;
```

In your controller method, use `@Validated` to specify the group

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loginiscorrect",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String LoginUser(@Validated(LoginGroup.class) kisitablo kisitablo, BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "login";
    }
    //Your logic.....
}
```

Moreover, for your registration page, if you want all username, password and email validated, you can specify as below.

Create a new `Interface` as `RegistratonGroup`

```
public interface RegistrationGroup {}
```

Your model:

```
private Integer userid;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your username.", groups={LoginGroup.class, RegistrationGroup.class})
private String username;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your password.", groups={LoginGroup.class, RegistrationGroup.class})
private String userpw;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your email.", groups={RegistrationGroup.class})
private String useremail;
```

And do same as before in your controller method and specify the `RegistrationGroup.class` as `@Validated(RegistrationGroup.class)`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{registration_path}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(@Validated(RegistrationGroup.class) kisitablo kisitablo, BindingResult result.....) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login";
        }
        //Your logic.....
    }
```

For more information, please [see here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.4#_requesting_groups)

Comment: Thank you so much.That's what I'm looking for

Comment: Glad it helped!